# How to pass derived type to abstract class with singleton

Tags: c#, singleton

This is the code that I use to apply Singleton pattern to all derived class.

```
public abstract class Service<T> where T : Service<T>, new()
{
    private static T _instance = null;

    public static T I()
    {
        if (_instance == null)
            _instance = new T();
        return _instance;
    }
}

public class DerivedService : Service<DerivedService>
{
    public DerivedService() { ... }
}

public class CustomService : DerivedService { ... }
```

So, when I use code `CustomService.I();` the type is `DerivedService` not the `CustomService`

Edit: <strike>I fix it by casting it to `CustomService` like this `(CustomService)CustomService.I()`.</strike> not work. (my bad sorry)

Is there any better way to do this without casting? Any idea, any suggestion?

Comment: Your should not use Singleton model with derivered classes - it's bad.

Comment: "I fix it by casting it to CustomService like this (CustomService)CustomService.I()."  Huh? Does that works?

Comment: @JenishRabadiya That will make the code not to compile. `new()` constraint expects you to have a public parameterless constructor.

Comment: There are lots of ways to make this "work" (i.e. compile) while having `CustomService.I()` return a `CustomService` but whether any of them is appropriate for your scenario is impossible to know.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel Yeah I realized that after I posted my comment.

Comment: The fact that you require the constructor to be public means this isn't really a singleton.  Anyone could create an instance of these classes.  Singletons lend themselves more to composition than inheritance.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel My bad sorry. So, Is there any another way to achieve this or I should write the singleton in each class instead in abstract

Comment: My suggestion. [Don't write a singleton at all](http://misko.hevery.com/2008/08/17/singletons-are-pathological-liars/)

Comment: @General-Doomer Would like to know why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem derives from the fact that the Derived class inherits like this:
DerivedService : Service<**DerivedService**> if you want the class to succeed you can write it like that:

```
public class DerivedService<T> : Service<T> where T : DerivedService<T>, new
{
    { ... } 
}
```